# Autoresizing Image in NSAttributedString with UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Im trying to make `UITextView` display rtfd document with image in it. The problem is, that the image is overlapping the frame of `UITextView` - it has larger width. I need this image to scale to width of `UITextView`. This is how I load the string:

```
if let text = try? NSMutableAttributedString(URL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("License agreement", withExtension: "rtfd")!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFDTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil) {

        textView.attributedText = text
    }
```

I also tried with webarchive file with `img style="width: 100%"`, but this also didn't work.

What is the best way to display rtfd or other document in such a way, so that images are scaled to fit the width?

Comment: Iterate through the `NSAttributedString` looking for attributed `NSAttachmentAttributeName`. Then you can resize your image according to the width of the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Larme for you comment, I managed to make it work like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    prepareTextImages()
}

private var text: NSMutableAttributedString?
private func prepareTextImages() {
    let width  = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) - self.containerView.frame.origin.x * 2 - 10
    text?.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, inRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: text!.length), options: [], usingBlock: { [width] (object, range, pointer) in
        let textViewAsAny: Any = self.textView
        if let attachment = object as? NSTextAttachment, let img = attachment.imageForBounds(self.textView.bounds, textContainer: textViewAsAny as? NSTextContainer, characterIndex: range.location) {
            if attachment.fileType == "public.png" {
                let aspect = img.size.width / img.size.height
                if img.size.width <= width {
                    attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)
                    return
                }
                let height = width / aspect
                attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            }
        }
        })
}
```

There is small problem with this - when scrolling I see a small lag when viewing this image. Doesn't happened with full size image without changing its size. Can someone think of a reason for this?

Comment: Why do you set again the attributed text in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Comment: You're right, I deleted this later. Forgot to change this here.

Comment: `attachment.imageForBounds()` now appears to be `attachment.image(forBounds: self.textView.bounds, textContainer: textViewAsAny as? NSTextContainer, characterIndex: range.location)`

Answer (score 0):

If you `po` the textView's `attributeText` property you can found it has many objects like this:

```
NSAttachment = "<NSTextAttachment: 0x6000002a39c0> \"XXXXXXX.jpg\"";
NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f8356400f60> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
NSKern = 0;
NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
NSStrokeWidth = 0;
```

Then you will find that the `NSTextAttachment` is the `Bingo`. So `enum` those objects, get the `NSTextAttachment` and change the bounds of it :
(I set the image has a 10px margin to right screen)

```
[attributeString enumerateAttribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id  _Nullable value, NSRange range, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

            if (value) {

                if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSTextAttachment class]]) {

                    NSTextAttachment *attach = value;
                    CGFloat scale  = SCREEN_WIDTH / attach.bounds.size.width;
                    CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(attach.bounds.origin.x, attach.bounds.origin.y,SCREEN_WIDTH-10, attach.bounds.size.height*scale);
                    attach.bounds  = newRect;
                }
            }
        }];
```